# Logical error in applying logarithm

Tags: matlab

In implementing a formula I get the error error (Attempted to access sum(0.0508041); index must be a positive integer or logical.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error (`Attempted to access sum(0.0508041); index must be a
positive integer or logical.`) is because you are using `sum` as a variable. NEVER use the name of a built-in MATLAB function as a variable name.  Instead of `sum`ming values, this line attempts to index the variable named `sum` with non-integer values in `lnR`.

Also, from one `i` to the next, you overwrite all previous values in `lnR`, having never used them. This also means that when you finally use `lnR` after the loop, it is just the `lnR` from the last loop iteration. AND, you should always pre-allocate arrays (e.g. `lnR = zeros(l2,1);`). Similarly, pre-allocate `x`, `y`, and `z` in lorenzo.m.

Comment: I corrected it and now it gives this error > Undefined function or variable "lnR".

Error in Takens(line 77)
r_i =  sum(lnR(:)). i have reposted the code with your correction pointed out.\

Comment: @SrishtiM I just ran your code from the post and don't get that error. Check the code in your editor.

Comment: I ran the code by pre-allocating lnR = zeros(l2,1);  (it is l2 and not 12). Now, I get logical error since the coding is incorrect. i am getting all r_i=0 and the value of takens dimension as infinity . Could you please provide the correct way of calculating the formula? Thank you for your time and effor.

Comment: I have no idea how to implement the correct formula.  But your code does not give an error any more, and it give an `r_i` that is a single scalar with a non-zero value.  Copy the code _from your post_ and try again because you appear to be running different code.

Comment: True, I was runnning something else. So, do you suggest that I again post afresh specifically directing towards the correct implementation?

Comment: @SrishtiM No need for a new post.  Just edit the question.  It will bump to the top.  Perhaps give a more descriptive title. I'd appreciate an upvote if helpful.  I'll keep helping to try to get a full answer for you.

Comment: This answer seems to cover the original problem properly. @SrishtiM If you get a new error or unexpected result, first try solving it yourself before asking here. With a little bit of searching you can probably solve quite a lot.

Comment: @SrishtiM I tend to agree with Dennis now. The original problem was solved and you will get more help with a new question. Please accept and acknowledge, then post a revised question.